# Set user_data for EC2 instance via Fog

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, fog

Does anybody know how can I set EC2 user_data via Fog framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `user_data` option for example

```
compute.servers.create :user_data => 'some data'
```